# Valohai local execution

Tags: python

I'm running python scripts with Valohai, using input files, like described here: [Download data](https://help.valohai.com/hc/en-us/articles/4419897109777-Download-data-to-your-job)

The usual command to create an execution and run it in a docker container in the cloud works fine:

```
vh exec run my_step --adhoc
```

But how can I execute the script locally, now? The function `valohai.inputs('dataset').path()` returns `None`, when I run it directly in my local venv. I would expect it to use the valohai.yaml. On the page [valohai inputs()](https://help.valohai.com/hc/en-us/articles/4421611364241-valohai-inputs-) they state `valohai-utils` would be

> Downloading the inputs for local runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [valohai inputs()](https://help.valohai.com/hc/en-us/articles/4421611364241-valohai-inputs-) page, the solution is already given - it is only unexpected. You need to add an additional code block like

```
valohai.prepare(
   step="my_step",
   default_inputs={
       "dataset": "https://valohaidemo.blob.core.windows.net/mnist/mnist.npz",
   },
)
```

There does not seem to be a way to read the valohai.yaml, instead. The idea of `valohai-utils` is the other way round: specify the steps in the code and generate the yaml. Well, would not have been my choice, but seems to be the only way to avoid duplication.

Afterwards, I came up with generic solution to read the valohai.yaml in python:

```
def is_running_in_valohai() -> bool:
    return bool(os.environ.get("VH_JOB_ID"))


def load_valohai_config_for_step(step_name):
    if not is_running_in_valohai():
        with open("valohai.yaml", "r") as valohai_yaml_stream:
            valohai_config = yaml.safe_load(valohai_yaml_stream)

        for entry in valohai_config:
            step = entry["step"]

            if step["name"] == step_name:
                valohai.prepare(
                    step=step["name"],
                    default_parameters={parameter["name"]: parameter["default"] for parameter in
                                        step["parameters"]},
                    default_inputs={input["name"]: input["default"] for input in step["inputs"]}
                )
```

To load parameters and inputs for a specific step, I can then call

```
load_valohai_config_for_step("my_step")
```